# CMUSphinx: What is the score of a recognised hypothesis?

Tags: cmusphinx

I wanted to know what the number/score associated with a **hypothesis** mean. In my recognized result, it is usually a negative number with a magnitude of tens of thousand. For example, a decoded hypothesis may look like **"What is an apple"** with an score being **-70021**. So I wonder if this score indicates the accuracy/confidence of the hypothesis. I have observed that this number could take a range of negative numbers, which doesn't seem to be related to confidence/probability/accuracy of decoded result. If it doesn't indicate the confidence, how can I set a threshold to hypothesis so that inaccurate result would be filtered out and prompting users for a repetition of his speech

ps. I am using pocketsphinx on Android. I get the score via calling **decoder.hyp().getBestScore()**

Answer (score 4):

> So I wonder if this score indicates the accuracy/confidence of the
>   hypothesis.

Score is the log-scale score of the audio matching the model (estimate of the audio generated by the model). It has nothing to do with accuracy and/or confidence. Confidence is available with ps_get_prob API call.

> I have observed that this number could take a range of negative numbers, which doesn't seem to be related to confidence/probability/accuracy of decoded result.

The numbers are negative because they are logarithm of a probability.

> If it doesn't indicate the confidence, how can I set a threshold to hypothesis so that inaccurate result would be filtered out and prompting users for a repetition of his speech

Threshold for verification of the keyphrase could be set with keyword spotting search implemented in subversion (branches/kws) and to be released soon. To enable it you need to set configuration -kws "phrase" -kws_threshold threshold.

Comment: Is there any java interface to the function ps_get_prob?

Comment: @Daniel It is log-scale of the score, to go to probability need to do 10^score_best/sum(10^score_i, for all i).

Comment: @Nikolay : is the KWS feature has been merged in the master branch? Regards